# Creating a matrix from the output of a variable inside a for loop

Tags: functions, matrix

I would like to enter the results of the following loop inside a matrix as its elements:

```
p=1;
q=4;

For[i = 0, i < p, i++,
  For[j = 1, j < q + 1, j++,
   For[h = 0, h < p, h++,
    For[k = 1 , k < q + 1, k++,
     Subscript[wtotal, m, i, j, h, k] = 
      Subscript[w, m, i, j, h, k  ] + Subscript[w1, m, i, j, h, k]
     ; Print[Subscript[wtotal, m, i, j, h, k]]]]
   ]
  ];
```

This matrix gives 16 values, so I would like to enter those 16 values inside a 4X4 matrix.
So how should I do it...

Further how should i convert the 4x4x4x4 table into a 16x16 matrix so that i can take its inverse.?

Comment: You'll want to look into using `Table[]` instead of `For[]`, for starters...

Comment: You do know that *Mathematica* starts indexing list elements at 1 instead of 0?

Answer (score 3):

You can either do an **iterative addition**:

```
p = 1; q = 4;
wtotal = Table[
  Subscript[w, m, i, j, h, k] + Subscript[w1, m, i, j, h, k], {i, 
   p}, {j, 2, q + 1}, {h, p}, {k, 2, q + 1}]
```

(since *Mathematica* starts indexing at 1, I've adjusted the iterators).

Or you can **add the two tables directly**:

```
p = 1; q = 4;
w = Table[
   Subscript["w", m, i, j, h, k], {i, p}, {j, 2, q + 1}, {h, p}, {k, 
    2, q + 1}];
w1 = Table[
   Subscript["w1", m, i, j, h, k], {i, p}, {j, 2, q + 1}, {h, p}, {k, 
    2, q + 1}];

wtotal = w + w1
```

Note that I used `"w"` instead of `w` inside subscripts to prevent a recursive calling.

Comment: thank you very much Istvan .the code is working and has helped me a lot for my assignment.                                       -best                                                           Pawan

Comment: @user4402: You're most welcome, have a nice time on *Mathematica*.SE!

Comment: i have another doubt, the matrix which i got is a 4x4x4x4 tensor, and i want to convert it into a 16x16 matrix to find its inverse, so how can i do that.?

Comment: @user4402 Which matrix do you refer to? Could you be a bit more specific? How do you want to convert it to a 2D matrix? Does `Partition[Flatten[matrix, 2], 16]` work for you?

Comment: I used the command of partition given by and the program worked so thank you once again..I just wanted to convert a table of 256 elements into a 16x16 matrix so i wrote the command as:-Partition[Flatten[matrix, 4], 16]

Comment: can you if possible give me your email-id Istavn ?

Comment: @user4402 Join me in [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6337/pawan-istvan) room please!